# Drupal : access restriction on comments

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, organic-groups, drupal-comments, drupal-permissions

I would like to have a restriction mechanism (access restrictions) on the comments that are posted on a node. In my system, all nodes are public. However, I would like the replies to be tied to Organic Groups so that only member of that group can view the reply. ( Ex. Groups could be **'Paid User Group' and 'Free Group'**)

Scenario:

there is a **forum topic** which is viewable publicly. 
It has **three replies**. Two posted publicily and one tied to Paid user group.

**when a free user logs in he sees the topic and two comments while a paid user sees the topic and all the three comments**.

How can this be achived in drupal 6? Will i need to buildmy own permissioning system?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Node comments](http://drupal.org/project/nodecomment) - one plus: comment will act as node, so you get all powerful of nodes, for example byuing access to comment node will autosupported by drupal ecommerce module ubercart.

Comment: thanks Nikit. This is not working well with Organic groups. i have a public forum topic, and a nodecomment on it that is privately shared with a particular group.  This nodecomment should ideally be visible only to the group members. But here it is visible to all users including non members of the group.